# Linux module compilation using multiple threads / jobs

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

When trying to compile a Linux module using -j2 i am getting the following error:

```
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
```

What is the correct way to parallel build multiple source files when building a Linux kernel module ?

Thanks,

Itay

Answer (score 0):

U may wanna see this specific line in **Makefile**

```
dpkg-buildpackage blablabla
```

warning message means this should be

```
+dpkg-buildpackage blablabla
```